# Can an attribute be normalized for all finder methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a Rails 5 model with an attribute that needs to be normalized, like a url or email.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  # Using the attribute_normalizer gem
  normalize_attributes :email, with :email

  ...
end
```

I want it so when finder methods are used on that model, that search attribute is also normalized. For example...

```
# This would match 'foo@example.com'
person = Person.find_by( email: 'FOO@EXAMPLE.COM' )

# This would also match 'foo@example.com'
person = Person.find_by( email: 'foo+extra@example.com' )
```

I tried providing my own `Person.find_by` thinking other finder methods would ultimately call it.

```
def self.find_by(*args)
  attrs = args.first
  normalize_email_attribute(attrs) if attrs.kind_of?(Hash) 
  super
end
```

That worked for `Person.find_by`, but despite internally Rails using `find_by` for other finder methods like `find_or_create_by`, they don't call `Person.find_by`. I have to override individual finder methods.

```
def self.find_or_create_by(attrs, &block)
  normalize_email_attribute(attrs)
  super
end

def self.find_or_create_by!(attrs, &block)
  normalize_email_attribute(attrs)
  super
end
```

Is there a way to normalize search attributes on a particular model for all finder methods? Or perhaps a better to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Despite this being almost 4 years old (!!), I'm surprised it did not get more attention as it seems like a very valid use-case. There is still no way to achieve that with Rails or a gem?

Comment: @AdrienK Not that I've found. A callback would be nice. I think the real answer is to apply the Repository Pattern.

Comment: @AdrienK this feature is appeared in edge rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 7.1 added [`ActiveRecord::Base::normalizes`](https://github.com/jonathanhefner/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/normalization.rb)

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :email, with: ->(email) { email.strip.downcase }
end
```

It works with both persistence and finder methods

```rb
User.create(email: " ASDF@ExAmPLE.com \n")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">

User.find_by(email: "\nasdf@examplE.CoM \t")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">
```